# Combine 2 dictionaries by key-value in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have not found a solution to my question, yet I hope it's trivial.
I have two dictionaries:

dictA:
contains the order number of a word in a text as key: word as value
e.g.

```
{0:'Roses',1:'are',2:'red'...12:'blue'}
```

dictB:
contains counts of those words in the text
e.g.

```
{'Roses':2,'are':4,'blue':1}
```

I want to replace the values in dictA by values in dictB via keys in dictB, checking for nones, replacing by 0.

So output should look like:

```
{0:2,1:4,2:0...12:1}
```

Is there a way for doing it, preferentially without introducing own functions?

Comment: Please indicate what you tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a *dictionary comprehension* and apply the `get` method of dict `B` to return `0` for items that are  not found in `B`:

```
>>> A = {0:'Roses',1:'are',2:'red', 12:'blue'}
>>> B = {'Roses':2,'are':4,'blue':1}
>>> {k: B.get(v, 0) for k, v in A.items()}
{0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 0, 12: 1}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. That was exactly what I was looking for.